# How I have to get data that store in database and uses in app of flask?

Tags: database, flask, secret-key

For example I have app on Flask with Postgresql. I have a some TOKENS and KEYS that stored in table `companies`. I need to get that tokens and keys in different places of my app. What the right way to do that? Any lazy approach?

Now I use app.config (but don't sure about app_context or before_first_request), for example:

```
with app.app_context():
    if current_user:
        app.config["CURRENT_COMPANY_ID"] = current_user.company_id
        app.config["YANDEX_TOKEN"]  =Company.query.filter_by(id=current_user.company_id).one().yandex_disk_token
```

or that:

```
with app.app_context():
    if current_user:
        g.company_id = current_user.company_id
        g.yandex_token  =Company.query.filter_by(id=current_user.company_id).one().yandex_disk_token
```

But that approaches sometimes lead to error that caused by current_user is None, or Company is None etc. And I can't recognize where and how I need store and get that TOKENS and KEY so all the users can use it after they are logged but not before that?

Answer (score 0):

Find out:

It needs to update `app.config` constants before every user's `request` done. But if the `current_user` is not allowed (is `None`) then it will arise error so to make the current_user to `not None` we must use decorator `@login_manager.request_loader`

for example that code is placed in `__init__` of app folder, and it solve two problems:

no empty `current_user` before every request we made to database via ORM.

no one `request` with empty `app.config` constants.

```
def set_config():
    app.config['CURRENT_COMPANY_ID'] = current_user.company_id
    app.config['YANDEX_TOKEN'] = Company.query.filter_by(id=current_user.company_id).first().yandex_disk_token


@login_manager.request_loader
def load_user_from_request(request):
    user_id = request.headers.get('User-ID')
    if user_id:
        return UserModel.query.get(user_id)
    return None


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        set_config()
```